# Javascript Array empty on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

i have a JS function that would send data to a server. In the function i fill a array(row_data) with data from input fields. The array is not empty and i can get values after i set them. But if i put the array to a ajax call, the array is completely empty. I dont't understand this behavior.

```
    function send_data() {
        var d = new Date();
        var row_data = [];
        timestamp = d.getTime();

        for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            row_data[i] = [];
            row_data[i]['bold'] = jQuery('#bold' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['italic'] = jQuery('#italic' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['underline'] = jQuery('#underline' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['align'] = jQuery('#align' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['capitalize'] = jQuery('#capitalize' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['curved'] = jQuery('#curved' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['font'] = jQuery('#font' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['font_size'] = jQuery('#fontsize' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['abstand'] = jQuery('#abstand' + i + '_val').val();
            row_data[i]['text'] = jQuery('#zeile' + i).val();

            if (row_data.length <1) alert("array is empty");
        }

        if (row_data.length <1) alert("array is empty");

        $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: server_script_url,
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'xml',
          data: {   'id': session_id,
                        'rows' : rows,
                        'row_data' : row_data
                    }
        })
        .done(function( xml ) {
            var image = $(xml).find('file').first().text();
            jQuery('#preview_image').attr('src', image + '?t=' + timestamp);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Leider gab es bei der Datenübermittlung einen unbekannten Fehler.');
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues there:

1. Array indexes start at `0`, not `1`, so your first entry will have the value `undefined`, which is probably throwing things off.
2. Separately, you're initializing `row_data[i]` to `[]` (a blank array), but then you're assigning it non-index properties as though it were an object, which is also probably confusing the serialization.

You can avoid #1 by using `push`; you can avoid #2 by using `{}` instead of `[]`. In fact, you can use an object literal to make the code a bit less repetitive overall:

```
for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
//                v----- Note { rather than [
    row_data.push({
        'bold':  jQuery('#bold' + i + '_val').val(),
        'italic':  jQuery('#italic' + i + '_val').val(),
        'underline':  jQuery('#underline' + i + '_val').val(),
        'align':  jQuery('#align' + i + '_val').val(),
        'capitalize':  jQuery('#capitalize' + i + '_val').val(),
        'curved':  jQuery('#curved' + i + '_val').val(),
        'font':  jQuery('#font' + i + '_val').val(),
        'font_size':  jQuery('#fontsize' + i + '_val').val(),
        'abstand':  jQuery('#abstand' + i + '_val').val(),
        'text':  jQuery('#zeile' + i).val()
    });
//  ^------------------- Note } rather than ]
}
if (row_data.length <1) alert("array is empty");
```

Separately, but probably unrelated, your `if` was inside the loop; you probably wanted it after the loop to handle the case where there were no rows added. I've moved it above.

---

Side note: Because none of your property names is an invalid "identifier name" in JavaScript, we can also leave off the quotes around them in the initializer:

```
for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
//                v----- Note { rather than [
    row_data.push({
        bold:  jQuery('#bold' + i + '_val').val(),
        italic:  jQuery('#italic' + i + '_val').val(),
        underline:  jQuery('#underline' + i + '_val').val(),
        align:  jQuery('#align' + i + '_val').val(),
        capitalize:  jQuery('#capitalize' + i + '_val').val(),
        curved:  jQuery('#curved' + i + '_val').val(),
        font:  jQuery('#font' + i + '_val').val(),
        font_size:  jQuery('#fontsize' + i + '_val').val(),
        abstand:  jQuery('#abstand' + i + '_val').val(),
        text:  jQuery('#zeile' + i).val()
    });
//  ^------------------- Note } rather than ]
}
if (row_data.length <1) alert("array is empty");
```

Comment: Also he need to change `for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++)` to `for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)` . I mean the `=` in for condition

Comment: @user1354678: Not necessarily, not if he wants selectors like `#bold_1_val` (rather than `#bold_0_val`). I'm assuming the `id`s in the HTML start with 1 rather than with 0.

Comment: Perfect, this works! My main failure was to define an array instead an object? Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: The if statement was only for testing purposes :-)

Comment: @Smedi: *"My main failure was to define an array instead an object?"* I think it was both things together ("failure" is a bit harsh! :-) ), but yes, it was probably primarily that the serialization code expected those arrays inside the `row_data` array to only have "indexes" (all-digits properties) rather than having properties with names. JavaScript arrays are unusual in that they can have both (because they're [not really arrays at all](http://http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)), and most serialization formats just ignore non-index properties.

Answer (score 0):

test this code

```
    for(var i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        row_data[i] = {};
        row_data[i]['bold'] = jQuery('#bold' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['italic'] = jQuery('#italic' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['underline'] = jQuery('#underline' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['align'] = jQuery('#align' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['capitalize'] = jQuery('#capitalize' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['curved'] = jQuery('#curved' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['font'] = jQuery('#font' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['font_size'] = jQuery('#fontsize' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['abstand'] = jQuery('#abstand' + i + '_val').val();
        row_data[i]['text'] = jQuery('#zeile' + i).val();

        if (row_data.length <1) alert("array is empty");
    }
```